# Using custom objects as parameters and return type with JAX-WS webservices

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, java-ee-6

I am learning Java webservices using the online documentation and came across below statement which states that not every class in the Java language can be used as a method parameter or return type in JAX-WS:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnazc.html

> JAX-WS delegates the mapping of Java programming language types to and
>   from XML definitions to JAXB. Application developers don’t need to
>   know the details of these mappings but should be aware that not every
>   class in the Java language can be used as a method parameter or return
>   type in JAX-WS.

Suppose I have an Employee object which contains reference to list of Address objects and I have a method say `getEmployee(int employeeId)` that searches employee records based on the employee id and returns the Employee object to the calling method. Now can I expose my method `getEmployee(int employeeId)` as web-service?

Also if I have an employee object and other objects like Manager, Clerk which extends this employee object. Then can I use this kind of relationship when I am using web-services? Are there any restrictions on how can I use inheritence with web-services?

The different posts in stackoverflow shows that we can pass/return custom objects with JAX-WS web-service, then what is the restriction that we have on them as mentioned in the document?

Comment: Note to limitation of object that can be used as param or returned value: the object that is passed as parameter or returned should be serialized that is why in case of object with references whole graph should be serialized. In you case there is employ bean and its refers to address bean that should be ok (if there is no references from address to another ones).